# Is it possible to use MMPCM for SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am currently working with MMPCM in SharePoint 2010. I want to get it worked in SharePoint 2013. So I want to know whether it is possible to use MMPCM for SharePoint 2013.